# How to extend this result for a regular arc to a regular curve?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a continuous function $f$ with an antiderivative $F$ defined on some $D \subset \mathbb{C}$. I want to show that for any regular curve $K$ joining two points $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$, the value of the integral

$$\int_Kf(z)dz$$

is constant and equal to $F(z_2)-F(z_1)$.

Currently I know that for a regular arc $A$, $$\int_A f(z)dz=\int_a^b f(z(t))z'(t)dt$$
where $z(t)$ is the parametrization of $A$. This result allows me to prove the theorem for a regular arc, but now I want to extend it to a regular curve. I guess I should express $K$ as a sum of regular arcs and then apply the previous result, but I'm not sure about the technicalities. Also, the notions of regular curves and arcs are confusing to me, and I can't really visualize the difference between a regular and nonregular curve. Also, wherever I look the definitions vary.

The definition I have is that a regular curve consists of a parametrization $\gamma : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where the interval $[a,b]$ can be partitioned into $n$ subintervals, such that $\gamma$ is $C^1$ on each one.

Edit: Here's what I have as preliminaries:

---

We call the ordered pair $\Gamma = (\gamma, |\Gamma|)$ a regular (piecewise smooth) curve on $\mathbb{C}$ if:

-The function $\gamma$ is such that $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \supset [a,b]  \rightarrow |\Gamma| \subset \mathbb{C}$, where $|\Gamma| = \gamma([a,b]) \neq \emptyset$.

-There exist $\{ t_k, \ k =0,1,...,n \} $ such that $a=t_0 < t_1 <...<t_n=b$ where $\gamma \in \mathcal{C}^1([t_{k-1},t_k])$ (restricted to that interval, don't know how to write that in tex) for each $k=1,...,n$.

The negative of a regular curve $\Gamma$ is denoted by $-\Gamma$ and stands for $(\gamma_1,|\Gamma|)$, where $\gamma_1 (t) = \gamma(-t), t \in [a,b]$.

A regular arc is just the same definition as above without the $t_k$'s and the $\gamma$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$ on the whole $[a,b]$.

---

For any such regular curve $K$, we have:

$$\int_K af(z)+bg(z)dz=a\int_Kf(z)dz+b\int_K g(z)dz$$
$$\int_K f(z)dz = -\int_{-K}f(z)dz$$

---

If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a complex function of a real variable, and $f(t) = u(t)+iv(t)$, then:

$$\int_a^b f(t)dt =\int_a^b u(t)dt +i\int_a^b v(t)dt$$

---

Now, given these preliminaries, I want to prove the theorem about $F(z_2)-F(z_1) first for a regular arc, then for a regular curve.

Comment: I've always found the notation using "$A$" in the integral to be funny since the integral depends not only on the image set of the curve but the parameterization, up to more than even just signs.  Anyway, can you say what proof it is you have of your fact that only works when the curve function is injective?  Cause the usual proof is just the fundamental theorem of calculus in 1-d, which works even if the real and imaginary parts of z may not be one one.

Comment: Does the definition of regular curve also include the requirement $\gamma\ne 0$ (on the intervals where $\gamma$ is $C^1$)?

Comment: I have edited the question with previous results and definitions.